# Can you iterate over only tags with the .children iterator from BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pulling down an xml file using BeautifulSoup with this code

```
dlink = r'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1040188/000104018820000126/primary_doc.xml'
dreq = requests.get(dlink).content
dsoup = BeautifulSoup(dreq, 'lxml')
```

There is a level I'm trying to access and then place the elements into a dictionary. I've got it working with this code:

```
if dsoup.otherincludedmanagerscount.text != '0':
    inclmgr = []
    for i in dsoup.find_all('othermanagers2info'):
        for m in i.find_all('othermanager2'):
            for o in m.find_all('othermanager'):
                imd={}
                if o.cik:
                    imd['cik'] = o.cik.text
                if o.form13ffilenumber:
                    imd['file_no'] = o.form13ffilenumber.text
                imd['name'] = o.find('name').text
                inclmgr.append(imd)
    comp_dict['incl_mgr'] = inclmgr
```

I assume its easier to use the .children or .descendants generators, but every time I run it, I get an error. Is there a way to only iterate over tags using the BeautifulSoup generators?

Something like this?

```
for i in dsoup.othermanagers2info.children:
        imd['cik'] = i.cik.text

AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'cik'
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: You can check the type of `i`. If it's a string, skip it.

Comment: @MendelG list of dicts

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I was hoping there was a shortcut besides isinstance(), but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `othermanagers2info` is a single item; you can create the same results using 1 for loop:

```
for i in dsoup.find('othermanagers2info').find_all('othermanager'):     
    imd={}
    if i.cik:
        imd['cik'] = i.cik.text
    if i.form13ffilenumber:
        imd['file_no'] = i.form13ffilenumber.text
    imd['name'] = i.find('name').text
    inclmgr.append(imd)
comp_dict['incl_mgr'] = inclmgr
```

You can also do `for i in dsoup.find('othermanagers2info').findChildren():`. However this will produce different results (unless you add additional code). It will flattened the list and include both parent & child items. You can also pass in a node name